# PowerShell Get Current Console Process

Tags: powershell

I would like to get the process ID or handle of the current powershell script when I double click and run a PS1 file from Windows Explorer.

This works:

```
$hwndPowerShell = Get-Process -Name "PowerShell"
```

But if I have multiple PowerShell console open, how do I get the handle of the current script?

I know one other way is to use the Win32 API FindWindow to find the latest instance of PowerShell console.

Comment: `$pid` <= automatic variable

Comment: Unfortunately, if I place the above in a ps1 file and run it, it returns two different values. `$hwndPowerShell = Get-Process -Name "PowerShell"
$hwndPowerShell.MainWindowHandle
$pid.MainWindowHandle
Pause
Exit
` Any thoughts on it Santiago?

Comment: I think it has to be done like this right? `(Get-Process -pid $pid).MainWindowHandle
`

Comment: LGTM @LiquidMetal

Answer (score 0):

Try this command ,in commandline property it will list the script path which we can use to identity the script and PID.

Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -filter "name = 'powershell.exe'" | Select-Object -property Name,CommandLine,HandleCount,ProcessID,WorkingSetSize,CreationDate

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul but unfortunately, I would face the same issue as if I was using `$hwndPowerShell = Get-Process -Name "PowerShell"` when there are multiple instance of powershell.exe.  I would not be able to differentiate which is the current process.  I did find the solution from Santiago's reply `(Get-Process -pid $pid).MainWindowHandle`